# Deleting files with same size from MinIo s§ bucket

Tags: server, minio

I have a problem. My service got spammed and now I have many files (111.895) and the most are with the same size (411.3 KiB) now I want to know how to delete them with a command or sth.

I already tried with ls -la but the size are the same only in bucket now...